# Losing data on converting MySQL latin1_swedish_ci to utf8_unicode_ci

Tags: mysql, utf-8, type-conversion, iso-8859-1

When I try to convert data from `latin1_swedish_ci` to `utf8_unicode_ci` I loose data ! The TEXT column is cut at the first special character.

For example:
[image]
Becomes:
[image]

Yet I tried many ways to convert my column and all solutions end up deleting data at the first special character!

I tried by phpMyAdmin or with this SQL request:

```
UPDATE `page` SET page_text = CONVERT(cast(CONVERT(page_text USING latin1) AS BINARY) USING utf8);
```

I also tried the php script :

https://github.com/nicjansma/mysql-convert-latin1-to-utf8/blob/master/mysql-convert-latin1-to-utf8.php

With all the time the same result, data are lost at first special character!

What should I do?

**UPDATE**

I could change the data to utf8 with

```
ALTER TABLE page CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4;
```

or

```
ALTER TABLE page CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

without loosing data but it does not display properly special characters.

Using the php function `utf8_encode($myvar);` does display correctly special characters.

Answer (score 2):

To convert a table, use

```
ALTER TABLE ... CONVERT TO ...
```

Or, to change individually columns, use

```
ALTER TABLE ... MODIFY COLUMN ...
```

Instead, you seem to have done something different.  For further analysis, please provide `SELECT col, HEX(col) ...` before and after the conversion, plus the conversion used.

See "truncated" in [*this*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf-8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored) .  The proper fix is found [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#fixes_for_various_cases), but depends on what you see from the HEX.

Comment: Strange, I could change the data to utf8 with `ALTER TABLE page CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4;` without loosing data but it does not display properly data and the php function `utf8_encode($page["page_text"]);` does display correctly special characters.

Comment: Don't use any encode/decode routines; they only compound the problem.  Provide the HEX so we can figure out what is wrong.

Comment: Do you mean select hex(column) from table ? `select hex(page_text) from page` is very very long.

Comment: @LondonSmith - Use `LEFT()` or `MID()` to isolate a chunk that includes some. accented text. For example, if `col` has some accents in the first 20 chars do `SELECT HEX(LEFT(col, 20)) ...`